# Larger iTunes Search API Song Preview

Tags: api, itunes, preview

Is possible get a longer song preview from iTunes Search API?
now it's return a 30 seconds long preview

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#understand

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

30 sec song previews are all that is available outside the store - the iTunes store reserves the 90 sec preview for users in the store.